# Binary operator '<' cannot be. applied to two 'Any?' operands

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I try to request data from web, then get an array for four times(they are different), and I tried to put these four arrays in a big array.
The problem is the four small arrays is not in the right place in the large array. What I thought is to use this function **largeArray.sort** to make the four little ones in the right position.
Here is my code:

```
for i in 0..<4{
    Alamofire.request(homeUrl[i], method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (valueGot) in
        switch valueGot.result.isSuccess{
        case true:
            let dataDict = valueGot.result.value as! NSDictionary
            let interestDict = dataDict["interest"] as! NSDictionary
            let issuesArray = interestDict["issues"] as! NSArray
            let todayDict = issuesArray[0] as! NSDictionary
            let articlesArray = todayDict["articles"] as! NSArray
            self.nsmArray.removeAllObjects()
            for oneDict in articlesArray{
                let model:ArticleModel = Mapper<ArticleModel>().map(JSON: oneDict as! [String:Any])!
                if model.cover != nil{
                    self.nsmArray.add(model)
                }
            }
            self.nsmArray.add(i)
                self.collectionNSMArray.add(self.nsmArray.mutableCopy()                  
            self.allCollectionView?.reloadData()

        case false:
            print(valueGot.error ?? "404")
        }
    }
}       //for循环结束
```

Here's the error:

```
collectionNSMArray.sort { (s1:NSMutableArray, s2:NSMutableArray) -> Bool in
    return s1.lastObject < s2.lastObject
}
```

[image]

Here's the model I did:

```
class ArticleModel: Mappable {

    var title:String?
    var snippet:String?
    var cover:String?
    var tags:[TagsType]?
    var webUrl:String?
    var appName:String?
    var appIcon:String?


    required init?(map: Map) {
        mapping(map: map)
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        title <- map["title"]
        snippet <- map["snippet"]
        cover <- map["cover"]
        tags <- map["tags"]
        webUrl <- map["webUrl"]
        appName <- map["appName"]
        appIcon <- map["appIcon"]
    }
}

class TagsType: Mappable {

    var name:String?

    required init?(map: Map) {
        mapping(map: map)
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Swift, use Swift collections. Do not use `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. In other words, rewrite your code to use the proper data types and these errors will go away.

Comment: And don't use `switch` statements on booleans... (use `if`)

Comment: Bump @nyg 's comment. There is no reason to `switch` on a boolean.

Comment: Agreed with rmaddy. It's possible to make this work with `NSDictionary` and `Array` but the code is very complicated an error-prone. Use `Dictionary` and `Array` and most of these issues evaporate. That said, if you use `[String:Any]`, this still won't work because you cannot compare two `Any`. Is "Bob" more or less than 4? Is 4 greater or less than a `UIViewController`? So you'll need to convert these to proper (non-`Any`) collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error, `Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Any?' operands` because you are trying to compare two values that `<` does not know how to compare.

- `<` is a binary operator
- `Any?` is the type of the objects you are trying to compare

You may consider casting `s1.lastObject` and `s2.lastObject` to something such as an number so that they can be compared.

Comment: Thx for your help, actually s1.lastObject and s2.lastObject are Int in the small arrays, but swift don't know what kind of type they are. What should I do?

Comment: You can force a type to an object using something called 'Casting'.

`var x: Any? = 2
print(type(of: x as! Int))`